# How to put a PLSQL parameter (:old.numero) within an UTL_HTTP.REQUEST statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, http, tomcat, plsql

I have a trigger in ORACLE PL/SQL like following :

```
create or replace TRIGGER HISTORISATION_PRIX 
BEFORE UPDATE OF PRIX
ON PRODUIT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
var VARCHAR2(30000);
BEGIN
var := SYS.UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('163.81.56.131:8019/Coctos/insertion?numero=:old.NUMERO&prix=:old.PRIX');
END;
```

As you see, inside my request, I want to put the parameters `:old.NUMERO` and `:old.PRIX`. But when I do that, the trigger does not work, I update my table PRODUIT but nothing happens.

But if I put some random numbers :

```
 var := SYS.UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('163.81.56.131:8019/Coctos/insertion?numero=45&prix=555');
END;
```

then it works perfectly.

So, how can I introduce the parameters `:old.NUMERO` and `:old.PRIX` within my request ?

Comment: "Hmmm...", said Cthulhu to himself, waking slowly from his ages-long sleep-of-death, "something has awakened me from my ages-long sleep-of-death. Umm...seems a bit damp-ish here in old R'lyeh... Feh. But what could it be? What could have called me back to Earth? Crazed priests waving wavy-bladed knives above altars en-strapped with scantily-clad virgins..? Nope. Crowds of dazed worshippers chanting my name? Nope. Hmmm...could it be...dare I hope for...b̛̕us͘ine̡͞s̨ş͜ ̡ļ͡o͜g̸͏įc͘ ̧͞͠in ̸a̷ ̴̢̛t̸ri̛͡g̷̢̛g̵̨é͝r̴̀?!? YESSSSSS!!! Fist-pump!!!!". Hungrily, he swam upwards towards the world...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've got ":old" within a string, which would mean that the literal value ":old.NUMERO" and ":old.PRIX" are being sent in your request instead of their values.

Try:

```
create or replace TRIGGER HISTORISATION_PRIX
    BEFORE UPDATE OF PRIX
ON PRODUIT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
var VARCHAR2(30000);
BEGIN
var := SYS.UTL_HTTP.REQUEST('163.81.56.131:8019/Coctos/insertion?numero=' || :old.NUMERO || '&prix=' || :old.PRIX);
END;
```

If that doesn't work, temporarily add an exception handler (before the `END;`) in your trigger and run an update directly on the table (from SQLPlus, with serveroutput on):

```
exception when others then 
  dbms_output.put_line(' Error Msg  : ' || SYS.UTL_HTTP.get_detailed_sqlcode  || SYS.UTL_HTTP.Get_Detailed_Sqlerrm);
```

Comment: Why catch others - if it gets an exception the session doing the update will see that anyway; and might not see the `dbms_output`?

Comment: It works fine, I finally found the solution and was about to post it but thanks !

Comment: @AlexPoole: I updated to clarify that a test update should be made directly on the database with serveroutput on.  I included the catch just for debugging purposes in case the OP still had issues after using my answer and could provide us with more info.